# Is it ok to have multiple versions on python on the same server?

Tags: python, server

I work in an office where python scripts are run in a server that has python 2.6 version installed.

We cannot switch to other versions since some scripts rely on it.

On the other hand, we need to run scripts that require other more recent versions of python. Is it possible to install on the same server two or more different versions?

If so, what would be the issues correlated with it? 
Is there the risk that versions get messed up failing the executions or somthing similar?

P.S. the server runs Linux

Comment: You can definitely do this. Look into using Python virtual environments (`virtualenv`) to make it easier. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: Yeah, python 2.x and python 3.x are not in conflict.

Comment: what if versions are 2.6 and 2.7

Comment: `virtualenv` is like splitting your machine into rooms with different python versions in each

Comment: @BlueMoon no problem using 2.6 and 2.7 on the same machine but you want make sure you dont mess with the system one (2.6 in your case) - but virtualenvs do solve the problem, really.